# Is this static variable thread safe in ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, thread-safety

I know this kind of thing has been asked many times on here but I'm still not completely understanding thread safety in ASP.

C#:
Where Util is a static class and theList is a static List.

```
Util.theList= new List<Object>();
 Util.theList.Add(someObject);
```

The page loads once, then a second later(1 SECOND AFTER POSTBACK) the Util.theList is populated and the page is reloaded to bind with newly populated list data:

```
this.Repeater.DataSource = Util.theList;
            this.Repeater.DataBind();
```

Each time theList is populated it is INSTANTIATED:

```
Util.theList= new List<Object>();
```

If this is not thread safe how can I make it thread safe? 
I can't have the list non static and on the same page because of a separate problem where the data only binds each time if it is bound on page_load:
[OnDataBind only fires on first postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058541/ondatabind-only-fires-on-first-postback)

Comment: What does having a static list buy you in this case? You are instantiating the list each time anyway?

Comment: Hi Kyle, it gives me access to that same list on the second postback. Whereas if it wasn't static the List would be empty on second postback

Comment: what usr states is correct, use the ViewState for postbacks.

Answer (score 6):

It is clearly unsafe because static variables are shared between requests. Move the list to some place that is unique to a particular request, like a page instance field.

If you need to pass state across postbacks use ViewState or some other non-global mechanism.

Comment: usr, from this link:http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/viewstate/ it states that viewstates are best used for simple data. I wan't to store a list of complex objects of which that page recommends I should use Sessions variables, but to me to store this data in session variables is a bit of a "hack"

Comment: Yes Session is wrong because the scope is wrong. You don't want to maintain this data for all pages the user visits. You want it for just the current page. Session is often misused and it leads to these annoying apps where you can't have multiple tabs open. Possible solution: Keep a dictionary<Guid, YourObject> in the session. Each page has a guid that is stored in viewstate. That gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: I will attempt your solution, but is there no better way I can do this? the only problem is that the list is only populated after page_load.

Comment: ASP.NET is lacking a feature called "conversations". A conversation is a session for just one page or a flow of pages. The dictionary I suggested is an implementation of that concept. I recommend it if you cannot use the simpler ViewState (why not?).

Answer (score 0):

Its best if you avoid static variables all together.
Static variables do not really fit well with unit testing. Static classes and variables cannot be stubbed or mocked.

However, in your instance, no the static variables are not thread safe.